# Matlab - Compar index's of a vector to convert to string

Tags: string, matlab, vector

I have a question where I go through a vector [1 4 2 3 8], and another ['JFMAMJJASOND'] and I need to create a string from the numbers in the first vector with the second one Ive got the code:

```
v1=['JFMAMJJAOSND'];
v2=v;

for i=1:n
    v2(i)=str(i);
    str(i)=v1(i);
end

disp(str);
```

The initial number vector is an input.

Im pretty sure my code above is way off I tried looping through both using two for loops aswell but couldnt create the string.

Comment: What output are you expecting from this example? What are `v`, `n`, and `str` in your code?

Comment: so if the inputted vector is [1 4 3 2 8] the outputted string expected is JAMFA.

Comment: Constructs a string from the vector v in 4(b) by replacing each integer in
v with the corresponding starting letter of the month corresponding to
that integer (that is 1 is replaced by J for January, 2 by F for February,...,
and 12 by D for December) Thats the full question

Comment: Assuming `v = [1 4 3 2 8]`, `str = v1(v);`

Comment: legend thanks so much didnt even need a loop